# new window closing immediately after it opens up

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-auth, react-new-window

hey folks I have written this code to open up the sign-in page from `next-auth` library in a new window using the `react-new-window` library but the problem with this code as soon as I click on the button the new window opens up and it immediately closes

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { signIn, useSession } from 'next-auth/react';

const SignInPage = () => {
    const { data: session, loading } = useSession();
    useEffect(() => {
        if(!loading && !session) void signIn('discord')
        if(!loading && session) window.close()
    }, [ session, loading ])
    return null
}

export default SignInPage
```

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import NewWindow from 'react-new-window';
import { signIn, useSession } from 'next-auth/react';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';

export default function Home() {
  const { data: session, status } = useSession();
  const [popup, setPopUp] = useState(false);
  return (
    <Box>
      <Button color="inherit" onClick={() => setPopUp(true)}>Login</Button>
      { popup && !session ? (
        <NewWindow url='./SignInPage' onUnload={() => setPopUp(false)} />
) : null }
    </Box>
)
}
```

after doing some debugging I found out that  `onUnload` in

```
<NewWindow url='./SignInPage' onUnload={() => setPopUp(false)} />
```

is executing automatically which is not supposed to execute automatically it should be triggered after I get the session
please help me in resolving this issue

Comment: Did you check the value of `loading` and `session` because it seems like this: `if(!loading && session) window.close()` is closing your window

Comment: no I didn't checked that

Comment: so I checked the code and the code is correct but just now accidentally I clicked on login button twice and the code worked so the problem is the code is not working on one click instead its working upon two clicks

Answer (score 0):

it works fine for me without `react-new-window`:

```
<Button onClick={() => window.open('./SignInPage', '_blank')?.focus()}>
  Sign In
</Button>
```